# Using Doctrine extension Translatable with API Pplatform

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation, api-platform.com, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to add a feature of multi language to my application using API Plateform and ReactJS.
I've installed StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle, I want to use the extension Translatable.
I send the local("EN" or "FR" etc) then I want to send response swtich the local.

```
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CountryRepository::class)
 */
class Country implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

services.yml

```
App\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber:
    arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
```

LocaleSubscriber.php

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct(string $defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

In the response of the webservice which allows me to get the list of countries there is no name field.

How can I get the names of the countries switch the language ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not very RESTfull to use the session, your api will no longer be stateless.

You can use the accept-language request header. Most browsers automatically send it with each request. Here is an event subscriber that puts it in symfonies request obect:

```
<?php
// src/EventSubscriber/LocaleSubscriber.php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $accept_language = $request->headers->get("accept-language");
        if (empty($accept_language)) {
            return;
        }
        $arr = HeaderUtils::split($accept_language, ',;');
        if (empty($arr[0][0])) {
            return;
        }

        // Symfony expects underscore instead of dash in locale
        $locale = str_replace('-', '_', $arr[0][0]);

        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

If you want the user to be able to choose the locale dynamically i suppose adding the accept-language request header from your own code with each request will override the default of the browser.

I made this EventSubscriber for [my tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform). Chapter 3 is about Localization and Internationalization. The api side was easy in comparision to the react client side.

Comment: BTW, don't you need to add some configuration to activate the Doctrine EventSubscriber that implements the functionality of Translatable?